# Google Sheets - new starting point for an array

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, running an array to transpose raw data into a readable format. The array forumula runs off of a row of data and am using the array to transpose the data into multiple rows. The issue is that for every additional row of raw data, I create five new rows of transposed data so the array formula breaks. Trying to make the array formula flex to added rows of data - any thought would be appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16GOsH-EUDm2IeRgUgEQ8LBEltQASfJ8hR6GXh-pqNcM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see I inadvertently edited the original. So I restored it to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16GOsH-EUDm2IeRgUgEQ8LBEltQASfJ8hR6GXh-pqNcM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My solution is at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t21BPoy3wJzDZxKV7KyZZMn5gqmPtddPX-6TWSFALGI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 2nd approach is at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EZZjidQT8l1jOhIEMJUbgbqceK76iNArLsU7qifg4Aw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use an array formula, you can use an indirect formula and modulo arithmetic and integer division to do this. In k2 put the formula `=indirect("A"&(3+FLOOR((row()-2)/5)))` which will get the date from column A row 3 until you get down to row 7, when it starts taking from row 4. This formula can be dragged down and will jump rows every 5 as desired.
Similarly for L2 place in `=indirect("B"&(3+FLOOR((row()-2)/5)))` which can also be dragged down (copied) the column.
For column m we need to cycle through c2,d2,e2,f2, and g2, so we need modulo (clock) arithmentic. So in m2 place the formula `=indirect(char(CODE("C")+(mod(ROW()-2,5)))&"2")`. Finally for quantity we need to do both the column cycling and the incrementing rows every 5, so the formula for n2 is `=indirect(char(CODE("C")+(mod(ROW()-2,5)))&(3+FLOOR((row()-2)/5)))`. That too can get copied on down. That should do it. There could definitely be more elegant ways.

I think not more elegant, but preserving the array formula would be `=3+floor((row()-2)/5)` in j2 and drag on down, and then adapt the array formula to: `={INDIRECT("A" & J2),INDIRECT("B"&J2),$C$2,INDIRECT("C"&J2);INDIRECT("A" & J2),INDIRECT("B"&J2),$D$2,INDIRECT("D"&J2);INDIRECT("A" & J2),INDIRECT("B"&J2),$E$2,INDIRECT("E"&J2);INDIRECT("A" & J2),INDIRECT("B"&J2),$F$2,INDIRECT("F"&J2);INDIRECT("A" & J2),INDIRECT("B"&J2),$G$2,INDIRECT("G"&J2)}` which can be copied to 5 rows below it where the J2's become J7's and you are processing the next desired row.